# Unable to update (corrupt?) page layouts via Metadata API. Error: Invalid field:xxx in related list:xxx

Tags: metadata-api, related-list, page-layout, action

Our application uses the Metadata API to make changes to page layouts. This mostly works great, but in the last month or so we've encountered several customer organizations where we get errors when we try saving certain page layouts. The errors are always something like these:

- Invalid field:ServiceDate in related list:RelatedLineItemList
- Invalid field:ASSET.SERIAL_NUMBER in related list:RelatedAssetList
- In field: excludeButtons, invalid action:FeedbackButton
- Invalid field:Sales_Order_RevAdv__c in related list:RelatedAssetList

I'm unable to find these fields on the layouts when I look in the Salesforce layout UI. My assumption is that the fields were deleted from Salesforce without removing them from the layout, but I'm really not sure.

How can I prevent this error? If it is indeed corrupted layouts, is it possible to fix the layouts from the UI (I'd rather not just omit the invalid fields from the Metadata API call)?